# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbName`.`#sql-e77_7`

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to add a column to a table and index it to another column. When executing the migration, it throws an error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbName`.`#sql-e77_7`, CONSTRAINT `fkName` FOREIGN KEY (`column`) REFERENCES `targetTable` (`targetColumn`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASC)
```

Can anyone explain to me how did that "#sql-e77_7" was generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add or update a row if the parent is not found , you should insert the row containing the parent , then insert the child .

Here an example 
i have this two tables exercice and exercice_entite

```
CREATE TABLE exercice
(
  exercice_id serial NOT NULL,
  date_debut date,
  date_fin date,
  exercice_etat text,
  exercice_code text,
  CONSTRAINT exercice_pkey PRIMARY KEY (exercice_id)
)

CREATE TABLE exercice_entite
(
  id_exercice_entite serial NOT NULL,
  id_exercice_pere integer,
  code_entite_filiale character varying(10),
  etat_exercice_entite text,
  code_exercice_entite text,
  code_entite_mm character varying(10),
  CONSTRAINT exercice_entite_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_exercice_entite),
  CONSTRAINT exercice_entite_code_entite_filiale_fkey FOREIGN KEY (code_entite_filiale)
      REFERENCES entite_filiale (code_entite_filiale) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT exercice_entite_code_entite_mm_fkey FOREIGN KEY (code_entite_mm)
      REFERENCES entite_mm (code_entite) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT exercice_entite_id_exercice_pere_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_exercice_pere)
      REFERENCES exercice (exercice_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

in this example parent table is exercice , child table is exercice_entite because each row in the table exercice_entite  has a foreign key id_exercice_pere that reference to the table exercice .

before inserting a new row in exercice_entite mysql check if there is a row in exercice that have the exercice_id equal to the value of id_exercice_pere in the inserted row

Comment: Can you update your answer and site example for the parent and child? That would be highly appreciated! :D

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Solved it! The problem was that the new column was set to "not nullable" and thus mysql set some integer value that was missing in the other table.